# PHPMailer If Statement For Two E-Mails

Tags: php, xml, phpmailer

I am trying to generate an e-mail that will be sent to an e-mail address depending on the result.  I am generating an XML document with PHP, and if the result length for the XML is 0 (meaning there was an error), I want to send it to one address.  If not, I want to send it to another.

This is how I am sending the e-mail now:

```
$toaddress = 'mail#1@blah.com; mail#2@blah.com';
$toArray = explode(";", $toaddress);
for ($x = 0; $x < count($toArray); $x++)
{
    $mail -> AddAddress(trim($toArray[$x]));
}
```

This sends the e-mail to both addresses.  How would I make that so that, depending on the XML result, it would send it to one or the other?  Thanks.

Comment: I know how to do an if statement... my problem was that when I was doing that I was getting errors saying that it couldn't send the e-mail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a very simple question. I guess something like this ought to do the trick:

```
if($xmlResult) {
    $mail->AddAddress($toArray[0]);
} else {
    $mail->AddAddress($toArray[1]);
}
```

...where `$xmlResult` is a true/false value that you'd set according to the conditions you need (you haven't given any info about the actual conditions required, so I can't help with that).

Comment: This worked! Strange... I tried this before and it didn't. I forgot to pass $mail into the function that was determining the length. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, I believe you could use PHP's [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function to check the size of the file and if the size is 0, then send to one address, and if not, send to another.

Something like:

```
$filename = 'file_name';

if (filesize($filename) === 0) {
    // send to address #1
} else {
    // send to address #2
}
```